# Python dataframe apply function groupby and per column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have a dataframe:

```
df = Condition A_value B_value
       15       2       3
       30       1       8
       45       5       1
       15       3       9
       30       4       6
       45       8       2
       15       5       2
       30       7       3
       45       9       1
       15       0       8
       30       8       7
       45       1       3
```

I want to apply `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`

On each column , by the type. (meaning it will scale the column `A_value` for rows where `condition=15`, then A_value for 30, 45 , and B_value for  15, then 30, then 45.
Is there a way to do it without iterating over all groups? (e.g one-liner?)

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for processing each column per groups separately with [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html), [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) is added for processing all columns without `Condition`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

f = lambda x: (StandardScaler().fit_transform(x.to_frame()))[:, 0]
df = df.set_index('Condition').groupby('Condition').transform(f).reset_index()
print (df)
    Condition   A_value   B_value
0          15 -0.277350 -0.821995
1          30 -1.460593  1.069045
2          45 -0.240966 -0.904534
3          15  0.277350  1.150793
4          30 -0.365148  0.000000
5          45  0.722897  0.301511
6          15  1.386750 -1.150793
7          30  0.730297 -1.603567
8          45  1.044185 -0.904534
9          15 -1.386750  0.821995
10         30  1.095445  0.534522
11         45 -1.526117  1.507557
```